# Compute string distance/difference in JavaScript?

Tags: jquery

I have to compare two strings, in that how much percentage str1 is contains str2.

```
str1="Hello wolrd"
str2="hello"
```

means `distance(str1, str2)` should return 50%.. like that.

Comment: What are the rules you want to implement?  Ie. does case sensitivity matter?  Are you counting how many words match out of total words and displaying that as a percentage?

Comment: "String distance" is a complex and active area of ongoing mathematical investigation.  There are various ways to measure it, such as the popular Levenshtein distance, and others, with different advantages and disadvantages, depending on the application.  Can you please give details about the application?  That is the only way to answer a question of this nature with something useful.

Comment: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance#JavaScript

Comment: Do you intend to match the words or characters?
Would 'hello' and 'he llo' return 100% or 0%?

Answer (score 0):

I am not a mathematician and can't show you a magic formula for something like this, however this example will get you started with recursion - please look at the code comments carefully:

```
/* same_words array should hold the following:
   ["john", "bbc", "hot", "red,", "xyz,", "apples,", "and", "likes"]

   NOTES:
    - The more words you add, the less the percentage will be... that's how percent works.
    - milk and MILK are the same word, but:  MILK and MILK, aren't the same because of the comma (same goes for periods).
*/

var  jSmith =  'JOHN smith LIKES bananas, HOT chocolate, AND APPLES, nonsense, RED, 321, XYZ, BBC or npr',
jSmithArray =  jSmith.trim().toLowerCase().split(' '); //Makes an array of words for jSmith

var  jDoe =  'JOHN doe LIKES oranges, milk, AND APPLES, XYZ, 123, RED, green, HOT and... cnn sucks, BBC rocks',
jDoeArray =  jDoe.trim().toLowerCase().split(' '); //Makes an array of words for jDoe

var bothJohns = jSmithArray.concat(jDoeArray); //console.log(bothJohns);

var c = 0; //counter
var same_words = []; //collection container


//collects all the words that occur in both sentences
function collectSimilarWords(word) {
  same_words.push(word);
}


//The w parameter holds the word "john" for the 1st time.
//The fn parameter holds always the collectSimilarWords() function.
function recur(w, fn) {
  for (var p in jSmithArray) { //Every property of the jSmithArray Array holds a word string.
    if (w) {
       if (w == jSmithArray[p]) { //If the word we passed in as a parameter is the same word as one of the jSmithArray elements...
           fn( jSmithArray[p] ); //...then pass this word to the collectSimilarWords() function.
       }
       c += 1; //Increase c so we can move to...
       recur(jDoeArray[c], collectSimilarWords); //...the next word recursively.
    }
  }
}

//Call recur() and pass in the first word of the jDoeArray as the 1st param, and a function as the 2nd param.
recur(jDoeArray[c], collectSimilarWords);


function calcWhatever(samewords) { //Feel free to calculate however you want.
   var percent = ( (samewords.length * 100) / bothJohns.length ).toFixed(2);
   var msg = "Out of Smith\'s plus Doe's words (total: " + bothJohns.length + "), about " + percent + "% (or " + same_words.length + ") of them are found in both of their sentences!";
   return msg;
}

//Hopefuly setTimeout() will log the same_words array when the recursive function has finished.
window.setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(same_words);
    console.log(  calcWhatever(same_words)  );
}, 1000);
```

Instead of a `for in` loop, you could as easily use a for loop like so:

```
for (var p = 0; p<jSmithArray.length; p++) { /* ... */ }
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try with below code.

```
<script>
var str1 = 'helloworld';
var str2 = 'hello';
var percent = 0;
var newstr = str1.search(str2);
if(newstr != -1){

    percent = (str2.length * 100)/str1.length;
   alert(percent+'%');

}else{
  alert(percent+'%');
}

</script>
```

if i understood your question, i'm sure this will help you.

Thanks.