# Approximate text matching in jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any way to do a Approximate text matching in jquery?

I have a div with the correct answer

```
<div class="correctAnswer" style="display:none;">CORRECT</div>
```

and i want that when the answer in the input tag is Approximate correct show some text

```
<input type="text"> //lets guess i type "CORREC"
<div class="Approximate" style="display:none;">Your answer is Approximate correct!</div>
```

Comment: How approximate is approximate? Correc will do. How about crrect? and Corre?

Comment: This isn't a jQuery problem...only you can define what counts for "approximately correct". Does `CRRCT` count? or `ORRECT`? or `ORECT`? The algorithm, whether comparison or regex or ??? is going to be up to you to implement.

Comment: You possibly want to look at using a soundex.  It's a phonetic value of a string... http://jsfromhell.com/string/soundex

Comment: [This is a complicated problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching). [The Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) is a common way to compute the "distance" between two strings. [Plugins exist](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+Levenshtein+distance).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compute string distance/difference in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169612/compute-string-distance-difference-in-javascript)

Comment: how about predefined nr of characters. lets say i have "correctword" as correct and input could bring the div if only 3 or 4 characters are wrong not more. **"crectword" <2 chars ok**... **"word" < 7 chars wrong < not ok**

Comment: how about predefined nr of characters. lets say i have "correctword" as correct and input could bring the div if only 3 or 4 characters are wrong not more. "crectword" <2 chars ok... "word" < 7 chars wrong < not ok

Comment: I think you might want to see Fegemo's answer then.

Comment: im not really trying to do a correction of the written text i just want to show another div

Comment: His answer isn't correcting the written text, it's giving a score of how well it compares to another string. What you do with the score is up to you

Comment: E.g. `if score > 5 return 'Your answer isn't close enough' else return 'Your answer is sorta close`

Comment: yes that worked sorry for the reply delay guess i was a little bit tired and lost it yesterday :P thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the Levenshtein Distance algorithm to do so, which will give you a score for the similarity of strings.

It is [well described on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) and has been used in a lot of different languages/technologies.

The pseudo algorithm is this:

```
int LevenshteinDistance(string s, string t)
{
  int len_s = length(s), len_t = length(t), cost = 0

  if(s[0] != t[0]) then cost = 1

  if(len_s == 0) then      return len_t
  elseif(len_t == 0) then  return len_s
  else                     return minimum(LevenshteinDistance(s[1..len_s-1], t) + 1,
                                      LevenshteinDistance(s, t[1..len_t-1]) + 1,
                                      LevenshteinDistance(s[1..len_s-1], t[1..len_t-1]) + cost)
}
```

You may also want to try [this javascript implementation on github](https://gist.github.com/979790) (which is not mine, BTW).